# UIProgress View in Recording app

Tags: iphone, avaudiorecorder, uiprogressview

I am adding uiprogreesView in recording app.When I tap start recording button It will  take few seconds to start recording and my progress view starts ,I also manged uilabels to get the recorded time.But my progess view is not synchronized with recording time.Actual recording time is less then progress view label.. Here is my code

```
- (IBAction)startRecordingButtonPressed:(id)sender {


recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]initWithURL:recordedFile
                                              settings:recordSetting error:&error];
        [recorder setDelegate:self];

        [recorder prepareToRecord];

        [recorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval)60];

        [recorder record];

        timeStartLabel.text != "0";
        progressView.progress = 0.0;

        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startjob)
                                 toTarget:self withObject:nil];

    }

- (void )startjob {

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool   alloc]init];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(moreProgress)
                           withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    [pool release];


}
- (void)moreProgress {

    float actual = [progressView progress];

    timeStartLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f" ,actual];

    if (actual < 1) {
        progressView.progress = actual + 0.01;
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 
                                         target:self 
                                       selector:@selector(moreProgress)
                                       userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    }

}
```

please help.And when I tap record button then button will go blue for few seconds and then I backs to its default color, then actual recording started but progress view started when button tapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use enable NSTimer to the given interval and in addition to use [CADisplayLink](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) that will enable you to update your display in accordance with time progress (You can get the fireDate from the NSTimer at any given point and update you progress bar according to that).

When NSTimer fires, you invalidate your display link (or you can just pause it for future replays..).

Example:

```
self.displayLink = [NSClassFromString(@"CADisplayLink") displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(drawView)];
[self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

and then in the drawView method :

```
NSDate* currTS = [NSDate date];
NSDate* fireTS = [self.captureTimer fireDate];
NSTimeInterval tsInterval = [fireTS timeIntervalSinceDate:currTS];

float newProgress = 1.0f - (tsInterval / self.intervalFromDefault);
```

when self.captureTimer is the NSTimer you've set with record method.

Comment: I did not use CADisplayLink. u have any example or link? other than u suggested in answer?

Comment: You can try [this one](http://files.slembcke.net/chipmunk/tutorials/SimpleObjectiveChipmunk/). Most of the uses are openGL related but it works great for more basic graphic reqs too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the progress is to show the time elapsed in some manner, can't you use `recorder.currentTime` in your updates? The timer stays as it is but the label and progress are update based on this property.

```
progressView.progress = recorder.currentTime / totalDuration;
timeStartLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", progressView.progress];
```

This way the `progressView` doesn't get updated before the actual recording starts.

**EDIT**

```
- (void) moreProgress {

    progressView.progress = recorder.currentTime / totalDuration; // Have totalDuration as ivar or replace it with '60' same as passed during recorder initialization.
    timeStartLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", progressView.progress];

    if ( recorder.recording ) {
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 
                                         target:self 
                                       selector:@selector(moreProgress)
                                       userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    }

}
```

Also if paused the timer won't be set. Either you can have a repeating timer and save a reference to it, or restart it in the delegate method `audioRecorderEndInterruption:withFlags:`.

Comment: but this doesn't explain the blue color. So might not be the true solution to your problem.

Comment: Blue color means..It is taking time to start recording.

Comment: Oh ok. I thought it was some UI glitch you were facing. So did it work?

Comment: hey progress view time is still not synchronizing with recording I used your code..I think It is happening because my record button is freezed for few seconds.what should I do?

Comment: Update the code in the problem. Hard to tell like this. Is the entire view freezing or just the record button?

Comment: just record button and when button comes to normal state progress view is starting with 0.03 second and If I stop recording at 17 seconds then original file is 10 or 12 seconds long

Comment: Check my code..StartrecordbuttonPressed; creating Audio session in - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 
 AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance]; //audio session instance 
 [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
 [audioSession setActive:YES error:&error];